# Before clustering should i do an analysis on time series?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, cluster-analysis, forecasting

I have a question. I have a lot of different items, different articles of a company, (26000) and i have the sell quantity of 52 weeks of 2017. I need to do a forecasting model for the future so I decided to do a cluster of items.

The goal is to show the quantity of items that were sold during 2017 in the similar quantity and for the new collection of items i do a classification based on the cluster and do a specific model forecasting for items. It’s my first time that i use machine learning so i need help.

Do I need to do an analysis about correlation before i do the cluster?

I can create a metric based on correlation that i put in my cluster function like the distance metric.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: Welcome to SO; your question is arguably off-topic here, since it is about methodology and not programming - please do take some time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Your question might be more appropriate for the [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) or [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) sister sites...

Answer (score 0):

Doing clustering on time series data cannot yield results on raw data.

Time series data is about trends and not actual values.

Try transforming your data to reflect some trends and the do clustering.

For example suppose your data is like **5,10,45,23**

Transform it to **0,1,1,0**. (1 means increase in value then previous). By doing so you can cluster the items which increases or decreases together.

This is just an opinion, you will have to try out various transformations and see what works on your data. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ is relevant place to ask such questions